My category is rigid: what this implies for representation theory?
I am studying a subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of modules for an associative noncommutative algebra $A$ (which is in fact also a Hopf algebra).
It is clear from our definition of $\mathcal{C}$ that it is an abelian symmetric monoidal category, which is nice. But recently, just out of curiosity, I proved that $\mathcal{C}$ is also rigid.
I would like to know what this implies for the representations of $A$. I have skimmed through a lot of books on category theory, and most of them mention rigid categories (so I think it has its relevance), but I am unaware of the consequences of this fact for representation theory.
Any comment with examples of the consequences of the rigidness of the category with details/references is welcome.

Are you working over a field? If so look up Tannakian categories.

What do you mean 'consequences [...] for representation theory'? Rigidity is itself a property of the category of representations, isn't it? What exactly are you looking for?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn I am asking myself if some proof or result we have for our modules would be simplified by invoking the fact that the category is rigid
